# How to add modification to all formulas from a selected range in excel

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to limit all of the formulas in a selected range of cells with an additional if statement.

Is it doable with the use of the VBA?

Let's say:
cell A1 contains =sum(B1;C1) but it can be any formula that a selected cell contains
after applying macro updated formula would be =if(D100>0;sum(B1;C1);0)

=if(D100>0;**any formula in a cell** ;0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this by using code like this:

```
Sub ModifyFormulas()
    Dim cl As Range, formulas_cells As Range
    Const template = "=if(D100>0,#,0)"  '# will be replaced by old formula without '='
    On Error Resume Next    ' handle an error if there are no formulas in the range
    Set formulas_cells = Range("A1:A10").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas)
    On Error GoTo 0
    If Not formulas_cells Is Nothing Then
        For Each cl In formulas_cells
            cl.Formula = Replace(template, "#", Mid(cl.Formula, 2))
        Next
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Super cool this works. Thank you. But how can I execute it only for cells with formulas not cells containing values or blank cells?

Comment: Looks like I've figured it out. Changing line [ For Each cl In Range("A1:A10") ] to [ Each cl In Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas) ] solves the problem. :)

Comment: @Tom0101 updated. Also error handler added

Answer (score 0):

Without vba, I use the following method:

1. edit / replace the "=" with "xyxy" - this stops excel recalculating
2. then edit / replace "sum" with "if(D100>0;sum"
3. then edit / replace ")" with ");0)"
4. lastly replace "xyxy" with "="

and then it all works, done this often with my sheets when I have to change some calculations...